# Editing ToC in a graphical way

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, xetex

I'm currently trying to make a custom document in latex. My table of content that I'm trying to recreate requires a lot of graphical rules and some formatting rules. So I would like to recreate the rules of the table of contents. Is this possible? I added a picture of the ToC I'm trying to recreate. Eventually, I will try the same with the chapters, but that seems easier than the ToC.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You may have a look at the [toc dedicated packages](https://ctan.org/search?phrase=toc) on CTAN as a starting point

Comment: It is entirely possible. Look around here with keyword etoc, framed package; there is somewhere around an answer from user "Gonzalo Medina," doing something very simillar.
It is highly advanced though.
But luckily, you will only need to increase font size of the numbers.